# wp query for popular post with simple field

Tags: wp-query, popular-posts, plugin-simple-fields

I used simple-fields plugin for one addition field(premium posts) and now I need to change the popular post widget. I need to get all popular post exclude premium post.

What I have tried so far,

original query,

```
$popularposts = new WP_Query('showposts=5&meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&ignore_sticky_posts=1')
```

edited query,

```
$args1 = array(
    'showposts' => 5,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => 'post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => DESC ),
        array( 'key' => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_1_numInSet_0', 'compare' =>'NOT EXISTS' ),
    ),
);
$popularposts = new WP_Query($args1);
```

But it doesn't provide expected results, it exclude premium posts(field : `_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_1_numInSet_0`) but it doesn't sort by `post_view_counts`.

Any help would be appreciate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query is:

```
$args1 = array(
    'showposts'           => 5,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
     //ORDER ARGUMENTS
    'meta_key'            => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby'             => 'meta_key_num',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    //META QUERY
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_1_numInSet_0',
            'compare' =>'NOT EXISTS' ),
    ),
);
$popularposts = new WP_Query($args1);
```

The order aguments are always outside `meta_query`, see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort inside a `meta_query`. The sorting parameters are invalid inside the `meta_query`.

You will need to move the sorting parameters to outside the `meta_query` and remember to set the `meta_key` which will be used for sorting

References:

- [`WP_Query` Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)
- [`WP_Query` Order and Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)